# How can I reset an Ajax success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
   $(document).on("click", ".example", function (event) {
        alert("test");
        var id = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: "update.php",
            data: {
                id: id,
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data); 
            }
        }) 
    });
```

If I remove this line...

```
 success: function (data) {
   $("#result").html(data); 
 }
```

... then "test" is alerted on every click only once.

But with this line every time I click on my `.example` button, "test" is alerted on more time.

So this means:

- First click --> alert "test"
- Second click --> alert "test", alert "test"
- Third click ---> alert "test, alert "test", alert "test"

... and so on.

I think it is caused because the `.example` button was also created by Ajax before.

So is there a possibility to reset somehow the success function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your script is initialised again and again on every success callacks, so just [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) the event before using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$(document).off("click", ".example").on("click", ".example", function (event) {
    alert("test");
    var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data); 
        }
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`Remove/Unbind` the old listener and add new like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".example", function (event) {
```

change it to:

```
$(document).off("click", ".example").on("click", ".example", function (event) {
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** The issue is your script is initialised again and again on every success callacks. So `$(documeon("click", ".example", function (event) {nt).off("click", ".example")` will unbind all listener and `on("click", ".example", function (event) {` add new one.

Answer (score 2):

this should help

```
   $(document).unbind("click").on("click", ".example", function (event) {
          //your code
    });
```

Unbind it so that it gets attached only once

> From [api.jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) Event handlers attached with .bind() can be
>   removed with .unbind(). In the simplest case, with no arguments,
>   .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements:

As suggested in comments by **charlietfl** use `off` as `unbind` is deprecated.

Comment: `bind()` and `unbind()` are deprecated. Use `off()`