# AJAX looping when remove many records

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using bootstrap modal before the confirm of a removal of a record:

```
$('#msg').html('Confirm?');
$('#modal').modal('show'); 
$("#modal").modal().find(".btn-yes").on("click", function(){                    
      $.ajax ({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "controllers/remove.php",
           data: {id : data['id']},
           sync: false,
           dataType: "text",                   
       }).done(function (data) { 
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);     
            if(data.sucesso){
                table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(); 
                $('#modal').modal('hide');                        
            } else {      
                $('#msg-error').html('Error'); 
            }         
         })
```

A loppping is happend in the AJAX when I am removing the records, e.g.

step 1 - I remove the first any record.

step 2 - I remove any second record, so the browser interpreter return in parameter 'data' the data os first record e after my second register

3 - If I remove the third record, the browser interpreter will return the first, the second records, so go successively.
The system doesn't show errors, but I feel that, when many records removed, the system gets more slow.

I am using DataTables, and in the row

```
table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
```

the record is removed e redraw the table.

---

I going to try explainer better.
The each event click in .btn-yes, my program remove one record of the table. The problem is that in the next records that I remove, its going send to kind of stack in memory. The slowness happend because the stack grow.
Example: 
I remove the record 5, when I remove o next record of the number 12, the AJAX is interpreter 2 times, one for the record five 5 e after for record 12, and so go sucessively.

Someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the slowness occurred in the client side not in the server ?

Comment: Of course, I debugin in browser and I saw. My database is localhost and has only 120 records

Comment: I got it resolve this problem, was only put the method .off() before method .on(). Follow the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586076/how-can-i-reset-an-ajax-success-function